# how to display a jpg or png image in front of an svg import with as grease pencil

Tags: image

[image]hi, I imported a png image into image as planes. Then I imported another svg image of a 2d character into import svg as grease pencil, and then I put the png image in front of the svg. But the svg is displayed as being in the foreground even though it is behind the png. how do I display a jpg or png image in front of the svg?

[image]

Comment: Hello, you can't have transparency with a JPG. As for the PNG, doesn't Alpha Hashed work? There are other solutions like importing a SVG instead of a PNG, or modeling the plane so that it has the shape of the table...

Comment: thank you for your answer, yes I tried with Alpha Hashed, but on the rendering the png image is behind the svg. I would like to avoid vectorizing because it degrades the image

Comment: Alpha Hashed should work, could you please pack your images (File >External Data > Pack Resources) and share your file?

Comment: i found the solution I'll give you the link to reddit they explain how to solve this problem.https://www.reddit.com/r/blender/comments/ikpo7i/grease_pencil_objects_are_overlapping_everything/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3

Comment: In that case, please add an answer so that if people meet the same problem they can find the answer here (Alpha Hashed or Alpha Clip + Z pass)